# Alfresco - Rename the CIFS share name

Tags: alfresco, samba, cifs

At the moment if I want to connect to the CIFS share advertised by Alfresco (CE) the path looks something like `smb://test-machine/alfresco/` when connecting from a mac. Is it possible to rename the share to anything else or place it on the root so that I could either get:

```
smb://test-machine/custom-name/
```

or just as the root

```
smb://test-machine/
```

I have been searching through the various documents and forums but not much info on if this is possible or if the share name is hard coded.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes - It is possible to change the context route from /alfresco to a custom name.

No - you cannot install it from server route `/`.

From the documentation;

> There are a number of updates that you need to make if you want to
>   deploy Alfresco to a context path that is not /alfresco. You cannot
>   install Alfresco at the server root (/). In other words, the context
>   path cannot be the server root.

The steps to change the context route can be found here;
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/deploy-contextpath.html

Comment: I feel a little silly now. I have been looking through the documentation but obviously not good enough since I could not find anything regarding that. Have 50 rep on me. :-)

Comment: @pieterk No problem, happens to all of us :) ty.